# How to get size of a HTMLElement with variable text after changing text in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-changedetection

I have created a component with an input attribute `text` and a public property `height`. After changing `text` the height of the component should be computed and set to the `height`property.

Problem: The HTML seems not to be rendered right after setting the text so that the height is 0. If I read the element's height in a `setTimeout()` call, I get the right height.

I uploaded the test project to StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivw9d7

What the app does is:

1. Set text of testComponent with lorem ipsum.
2. Get height right after setting the text and write it to the console.
3. Get height right 2 seconds after setting the text and write it to the console.

In step 2. the height is 0, in step 3. the height is as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` property of the `TestComponent` is bound to the `testText` property of `AppComponent`:

```
<app-test-component #testComponent [text]="testText"></app-test-component>
```

and you trigger change detection when the `text` property is modified in the `TestComponent`:

```
@Input() set text(value: string) {
  this._text = value;
  this.cd.markForCheck();
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

---

The problem is that when you modify `testText` in `AppComponent`, the `text` property setter in `TestComponent` will be called only at the next change detection cycle. You can elmininate the delay by forcing change detection as soon as `testText` is modified in `AppComponent`:

```
this.testText = "Some new text";
this.cd.detectChanges();
console.log(`height right after changing is ${this.testComponent.height}`);
```

To make sure that change detection is always triggered after modifying `testText`, you could define it as a getter/setter property, and call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` in the setter:

```
public _testText = '';

get testText(): string {
  return this._testText;
}
set testText(value: string) {
  this._testText = value;
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

With that code in place, you don't need to force change detection in the `TestComponent`.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epvn1m) for a demo.

Comment: Does this work with objects instead of strings, too? I mean if ``text`` in test-component was an attribute of an object used as Input property and the output in test-component.html was {{testObj.text}}?

Comment: This answer addresses the issue raised in the question. If you have additional requirements, you can include them in the question, or ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything and just not checking the log after your view is initialized.

Add your console in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.
Your view itself is not initialized in `ngOnInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(`height right after changing is ${this.testComponent.height}`);
}
```

**Debugging**

When you are trying to get the element's height in `ngOnInit()`, try adding this as well to the console:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.testComponent.el));
```

You will see the output in the console as: `{"nativeElement":{}}`
See, no element, so no height. (**Note**: It is important to "stringify" the console otherwise the log will have updated value).

There is no need to call manual change detections and setTimeouts to get the updated value.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I really need the new height right after changing the text. Do I really have to wait until the view is initialized?

Comment: @geronimo678 Of course you have to wait until the view is initialized, What height will be calculated if the DOM itself doesn't conatin the element when you are trying to fetch it's height.

Comment: The text will be changed more often than at the beginning. Do I need to use ngAfterViewChecked for the other changes? Because AfterViewInit is called only once...

Comment: @geronimo678: That depends on how much computation you are doing in `ngAfterViewChecked`. If the computation/logic is heavy then I will say no, not to use `ngAfterViewChecked` hook, it will be called almost everytime you do anything in your app.

Comment: @geronimo678: Where and how do you change the text?

Comment: Yes, I think I have to give some more information about the context. I want to create a popover component that has dynamic content (text). Right after setting the text I have to change the location of the popover relative to the target's position. Because the popover should be fully over the target I need the popover's height. The target itself can be an element in a content editable div.